# Vue watcher checked all checkbox when user deselect all?

Tags: vue.js

I use an array `['one', 'two', 'three']` to create combo box and binding with v-model `selectValue`, and then add watcher on that v-model to check all the checkbox when the user deselects all options

```
watch: {
  selectValue(newVal) {
    if(newVal.length===0)
       this.selectValue = ['one', 'two', 'three']
  }
}
```

When I log the value out. It shows that the `selectValue` value contains three values `['one', 'two', 'three']`, but in UI the last deselect checkbox not being checked, but when I wrap around the assign statement with `setTimeout` it works (without time out).
Is there any other options to do this. Should I use `setTimeout` like current?

Comment: Try `this.$set(this, 'selectValue', ['one', 'two', 'three'])` in place of `this.selectValue = ['one', 'two', 'three']`

Comment: @ShivamSingh it not working, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a proxy computed value with a setter:

```
data: () => ({
    items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    value : []
  }),
computed : {
    _value : {
      get () {
        return this.value
      },
      set (val) {
        this.value = val.length ? val : this.items
      },
    }
  }
```

then link your v-model to your proxy computed value:

```
<v-select
   v-model="_value"
   :items="items"
   multiple
></v-select>
```

working example: https://codepen.io/ellisdod/pen/poJqvgJ